# The connectionstring property has not been initialized error in c# winform app

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a desktop app. I created a database and now I want to show the data of the table in a `DataGridView`, but I get an error

> The connectionstring property has not been initialized

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace PetanqueAppTrial
{
    public partial class PTeamForm : Form
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Avichai\Desktop\Petanque with DB\PetanqueAppTrial\PetanqueAppTrial\PetanqueDataBaseNew.mdf;Integrated Security=True");

        public PTeamForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            filldata();
        }

        void filldata()
        {
            using (con)
            {
                con.Open();

                using (SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Players]", con))
                {
                    DataTable t = new DataTable();
                    a.Fill(t);
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = t;
                }

                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You should create the `SqlConnection` object in the `using` line, as that block disposes the object at the end, just like you are doing with the `SqlDataAdapter`. Although I don't think that will solve your issue, unless `filldata` is called more than once. And you can omit the `con.Close()` as the `using` closes the connection when disposing the object.

Answer (score 0):

`con` needs to be a local variable:

```
void filldata()
{
    using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Players]", con))
        {
            DataTable t = new DataTable();
            a.Fill(t);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = t;
        }
    }
}
```